# Boot error when attempting to install Kinect driver

Tags: raspbian, camera, kernel

I am trying to install the kernel driver to use the xbox kinect with my Rpi model B.

I have followed the commands found here https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect under example for Rpi with the exception of changing 3.12.y to 4.1.y to match my version.  I do not get any error messages up till the reboot command.

after reboot I get a blank screen with no command prompt.  If I restart and use NOOBs recovery to remove the line kernel=linux-4.1.y from config I can boot again but obviously don't have the new kernel with the Kinect Drivers.

since I got no error messages on the prior commands and no feedback but a black screen on reboot i am not sure where to begin debugging. I have looked for similar issues but most had error messages at some point which i do not get. any idea where to look?